# Using WinPcap in VC++ programs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, winpcap

I am trying to include [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) library in one of my Visual C++ program and I am using Visual Studio 10 Ultimate.

In the [documentation](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcapsamps.html) it says

> To add a preprocessor definition, you
>   must select Properties from the
>   Project menu, then select C/C++ from
>   the list control on the left, and
>   under the category Preprocessor, you
>   must add the definition under the
>   Preprocessor Definitions text box.

**Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions-> Added `WPCAP`**

I have performed this step successfully, then

> To add a new library to the project,
>   you must select Properties from the
>   Project menu, then select Linker from
>   the list control on the left, and
>   under the category Input add the name
>   of the new library in the Additional
>   Dependencies text box.

**Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> Added `wpcap.lib`**

Now I have problem while performing the third step.

> To add a new path where Microsoft
>   Visual Studio will look for the
>   libraries, you must select Options
>   from the Tools menu, then Project and
>   Solutions from the list control on the
>   left, VC++ Directories, then choose
>   Library Files in the Show directories
>   for combobox, and the add the path in
>   the box below.

Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> VC++ Directories.

Here it says *VC++ Directories editing in Tools > Options has been deprecated.*

[image]

Now where is this user property sheet located ? Can some one point me in a right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now a project property and located in project properties -> VC++ Directories.