# Linker errors with WinPcap

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winpcap

I'm using WinPcap library in a visual C++ project. When I try to compile the project I get linker errors however I've correctly configured the project properties to include the appropriate files and libraries. 
Here are the errors I got :

```
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pcap_findalldevs_ex referenced in function _main consolewinpcap.obj
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pcap_geterr referenced in function _main consolewinpcap.obj
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pcap_next_ex referenced in function _main consolewinpcap.obj
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pcap_open referenced in function _main consolewinpcap.obj
```

---

***UPDATE :***

Here is a part of the `".vcproj"` file

```
<Tool
   Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
   Optimization="0"
   AdditionalIncludeDirectories=".\WinPCap\Include"
   PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;WPCAP"
   MinimalRebuild="true"
   BasicRuntimeChecks="3"
   RuntimeLibrary="3"
   UsePrecompiledHeader="2"
   WarningLevel="3"
   DebugInformationFormat="4"
/>
<Tool
   Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
/>
<Tool
   Name="VCResourceCompilerTool"
/>
<Tool
   Name="VCPreLinkEventTool"
/>
<Tool
   Name="VCLinkerTool"
   AdditionalDependencies="wpcap.lib Packet.lib"
   ShowProgress="0"
   LinkIncremental="2"
   AdditionalLibraryDirectories=".\WinPCap\lib"
   GenerateDebugInformation="true"
   SubSystem="2"
   TargetMachine="1"
/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: WinPcap is a dynamic library, isn't it? Have you added the import library to your libraries to link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218929/using-winpcap-in-vc-programs?rq=1

Comment: yes I did import them :/

Comment: You could enable "Show Progress" in the Linker/General tab to see what's going on, e.g. if the library is really searched.

Comment: @harper I couldn't find where it comes from :( **Please** check my update

Comment: <Tool Name="VCLinkerTool" ShowProgress="1" ... />

Comment: @harper I've noticed that I have two "wpcap.lib" files in my project directory (one under "MyProject" and the other under "Myproject\WinPCap")and that's what made the Linker confused. I deleted one of them and now everything works fine.
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doubt about the linker process it's useful to enable the "Show Progress" option. You find it in the Linker/General tab.

If you don't use the GUI you can also change the .vcproject file. You find it here:

```
<Tool Name="VCLinkerTool"
    ShowProgress="1"
    ...
/>
```